# Negative value of source in MPI_Irecv function

Tags: mpi, mpich

I am running an MPI code and I am encountering some strange behavior with MPICH. In the MPI_Irecv call, when I print the source, I found source=-2. and I have this problem only for MPI_Irecv function.

Here, the print result:

```
MPI_Irecv, Received buffer 0x1398c00, count=1, source=-2, tag=1073741795, MPI processes=4
```

Could you help me please.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You must add some context to your question. Is -2 your choice? Or is it the result of a special value, for example MPI_PROC_NULL (https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node53.html)?

Comment: also check how MPI_ANY_SOURCE is defined in mpi.h

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, It's MPI_ANY_SOURCE